# How can i select only one grid in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
var iconSize by remember { mutableStateOf(50.dp)}
var boxBorder by remember { mutableStateOf(1.dp)}

LazyVerticalGrid(
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
            content = {

                items(itemList){ item ->

                    var isSelected by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}

                    if(isSelected){
                        iconSize = 70.dp
                        boxBorder = 2.dp
                    }else{
                        iconSize = 50.dp
                        boxBorder = 1.dp
                    }

                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .border(boxBorder)
                        .clickable {isSelected = !isSelected}
                    ){
                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier
                            .size(iconSize),
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Settings,
                            contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
```

This is my view, i want to only select one of them. I don't want to multiple selection, i want to single selection.

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `remember` inside `items` will be reset when the view of a particular item disappears from the screen while scrolling. You need to move it to the container level, then its lifecycle will be bound to `LazyVerticalGrid` itself.

You can now store the selected item instead of a boolean value.

```
var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf<Item?>(null) }

LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
    content = {
        items(itemList){ item ->

            val isSelected = item == selectedItem

            Modifier.clickable { selectedItem = item }
```

If your `itemList` is modifiable, the most stable solution is to store the id of the selected item. If only item content can be changed and the order/number is stable, you can also use the index of the selected items.